# c++ debug overloading operator

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Booking 
{
    double bT;
    double aT;
    double dT;
};

class New 
{
private:
    std::vector<Booking> v;

public:
    void gB(double bR, double aR, double dR, double startTime)
    {
        double bT = startTime - (1.0 / bR);
        double aT = bT - (1.0 / aR);
        double dT = aT - (1.0 / dR);

        v.push_back({ bT, aT, dT });
    }
};

int main()
{
    New book;
    std::cout << book.gB(5, 6, 7, 0, 3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

how can I possibly write these code to screen? The warning keep appearing as no match for `operator<<` (operand types are `std::ostream` {aka `std::basic_ostream<char>`} and `void`)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The error you are getting is becuse your function doesn't have a printable return value (`void` means your function doesn't return anything, so what do you want to print?)

Comment: Note that `gB` returns `void`, so you can't really print it's return value...
What exactly are you trying to print?

Comment: What do you want to print ? `New::gB` returns `void`

Comment: Have you considered using google, or similar? One of the first matches https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx (pretty sure that is what you're after, though I'm not sure what the *debug* in your question refers to)

Comment: @Shawn, Since the gB() function doesn't return any value (`void` return type), I wonder what you were thinking.

Comment: I understand what you guys mean.but is that possible to return the function without the changing of void? Is there anything that I could add?

Comment: @Shawn can you explain what you want to print exactly? e.g. give some sample output

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for:
Declare

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Booking& b)
{
    return os<<b.bT<<" "<<b.dT<<" "<<b.aT;
}
```

and declare public method in class New:

```
 Booking getV(int i) const { return v[i];}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Booking& b);
```

and replace this:

```
 std::cout<<book.gB(5,6,7,0,3)<<std::endl;
```

with

```
book.gB(5,6,7,0,3);
std::cout<<book.getV(i); //i represent number of booking in v
```

Comment: I'd also suggest `Booking getV(int i) const { return v[i]; }`

Comment: The `operator<<` would be a free function, not a class member

Comment: Member overloaded operators must have that class as lefthand operand, but that is not the case for `cout << book` .

Comment: @M.M oh I mean `Booking getV(int i) const { return v[i]; }`. What does it really do? And my code is working now!! thank you so much!

Comment: `const` means that you can call it on a const object. Typically you would use that for any function which does not change the state of the object